# how to include same file in different directory?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, url, path, directory

Directory structure :

*Main directory structure*

> ```
>      home.php 
>      thankyou.php
> ```

*Php directory structure*

> ```
>      root directory/php/date.php
> ```

*Include directory structure*

> ```
>      root directory/include/header.php
>      root directory/include/footer.php
> ```

*Images directory structure*

```
      root directory/images/logo.png
      root directory/images/abc.jpg
```

For date.php,  i want to use header and footer.php files. but images are not shown.
 i written below code

```
 <?php require_once '../include/header.php';?>
```

But when i used for home and thankyou.php, It is working fine.

In header file, code for images

```
<a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo" class="image"></a>
```

i dont want to change directory for date.php. And `not interested to absolute path` for images.

What to do so that images will be see in both directory()

Comment: Can you use base HTML tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: @doubleui `base tag` is same as `absolute path`

Comment: Maybe create a symlink for images directory? If your filesystem supports.

Comment: @doubleui how to create symlink?

Comment: On unix (no Windows support): ln -s root-directory/images root-directory/php/images . Read more on wiki: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Used base html tag as doubleui told me in head section

```
<head>
<base href="root directory/images/" target="_blank">
</head>
```